# Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://provider:xxxxxx@192.168.15.29:9200/"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://provider:xxxxxx@192.168.15.29:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://192.168.15.29:9200/'"}

Logstash URL is not working. Im trying to transfer data from my mongoDB to elastic. For that the logstash URL should work. Can someone help ?

Comment: 401 means that the authentication failed. Are you sure you're using a user that has the right to connect to ES?

Answer (score 0):

### An HTTP 401 error code in Elasticsearch means that the user is not authorized to access the requested resource.

you are using **provider** user. Make sure that the user has privileges to write.

you can test it with curl:

```
curl -XPOST "https://192.168.15.29:9200/test-index/_bulk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{ "index":{ } }
{ "@timestamp": "2099-05-06T16:21:15.000Z", "message": "192.0.2.42 - - [06/May/2099:16:21:15 +0000] \"GET /images/bg.jpg HTTP/1.0\" 200 24736"}
' -u provider:password
```

test with superuser (**elastic**):

```
curl "https://localhost:9200" -k -u elastic:password
```

OR

```
curl "http://localhost:9200" -k -u elastic:password
```

if you don't remember the password you can reset the [elastic user password](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reset-password.html).

```
bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic -i
```